# Is it true that cyclic subgroups are always normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups

There is a proposition that I'm supposed to "prove", but it doesn't sound true to me. It says that if $H$ is a cyclic subgroup of a group $G$ (notation $H<G$), then every $K <H$ is normal in $G$.

If that were the case, since $H<H$, we'd have a corollary: If $H$ is cyclic, then $H$ is normal in $G$. But is that even true?

Comment: That is surely false. Consider any cyclic subgroup of order $2$ in $S_3$.

Comment: That was a very easy counterexample!

Comment: Here you cleaerly need a non-abelian group in order to have a counterexample, and $S_3$ is the smallest non-abelian group. What examples did you consider before asking the question? Did you consider any example at all? You should.

Comment: I considered the quaternions, first $H = <i>$ and then $H=<j>$, but it was no use because $H$ turned out normal :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not true that if $H$ is a cyclic subgroup of $G$ then it is a normal subgroup of $G$. For a simple counterexample, let $G=S_3$ and let $H$ be the subgroup generated by the transposition $(12)$.

Perhaps the problem should instead read "every $K\leq H$ is normal in $H$".

Comment: I see, that's a clear counterexample. And yes, when one replaces "normal in $G$" with "normal in $H$", it's actually a simple proof!